# How to get the current date and time in YYYY-MM-DD HH: MM? LARAVEL 4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, datetime, laravel-4

I have a table `transaction`, inside there is column `order_on_sale` with default `value is 0`. Then i also have a table `config`, inside there is column `name` with two value that is `sale_start_date` and `sale_finish_date`. And there are also `time` columns with values ​`​2018-05-1 18:00` and `2018-05-31 18:00` `(YYYY-MM-DD HH: mm)`.
`name` and `time` columns contained in the `config` table are interconnected,
`sale_start_date = 2018-05-1 18:00`
`sale_finish_date = 2018-05-31 18:00`

then when someone orders on `sale_start_date` and `sale_finish_date`, the `order_on_sale` column contained in `transaction` table will change its `value to 1`
how do i get the current current time (YYYY-MM-DD HH: mm) to make the change?

```
$transaksi = new Transaction;
$order_on_sale = 0;
if (Config::get('sale_start_date') && Config::get('sale_finish_date')) {
    $order_on_sale = 1;
}
$transaksi->order_on_sale = $order_on_sale;
$transaksi->save();
```

Below is my code, but I am confused how to get the current date and time if I write such code

thanks for the answers you provide

Comment: Laravel comes with [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/), which has a lot of great functions for DateTime formatting, comparisons, and manipulation.

Answer (score 3):

A bit late answer for questioner but maybe can help someone:

```
$date = Carbon::now();
$formatedDate = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo($formatedDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

use the [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-instantiation) Library which comes by default with laravel

```
$date = Carbon::now();// will get you the current date, time 

dd($date->format("Y-M-D H:m")); //this will dump the date time in the desired format
```

Comment: This outputs "2018201820182018-MayMay-FriFri 1616:0505"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

$Now = Carbon::now(new \DateTimeZone('My/TimeZoneifRequired'))->toDateTimeString();
```

Answer (score 0):

So have you tried using Carbon Class ? as far as i know Laravel 4 supports it.

you can get your current date by doing

```
$now = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
```

This will retrieve the current date in the following format **YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss** (*as default*)

if you want to get the current date in your mentioned format **YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm**

by wrapping around Carbon and adding some php functionality you can get so :

```
$currentTime = Carbon::now()->toTimeString();
$now = Carbon::now()->toDateString() .' '.  substr($currentTime, 0, strrpos( $currentTime, ':') ) ;
```

For further explanation go for the docs : https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

simply you can use the below code on the view page.

```
<p>{{ date('Y-m-d') }}</p>
```

note: HTML  `<p>` tag is optional.

with hours and minutes

```
<p>{{ date('Y-m-d H:m') }}</p>
```